# Mkdocs material - change the default icon doesnt works

Tags: git, github, material-design, github-pages, mkdocs

We are using `mkdocks` and we want to change the default icon (education) which is coming out of box when you using Mk-docs, we have created `.png` file with the icon and
add it to the GitHub repo, but when you provide the link to it you don't see anything

**I try with**

```
theme:
  name: 'material'
  logo:
     icon: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NVM/my-tool/master/logo.png’
```

And also directly the link

https://github.com/NVM/my-tool/blob/master/logo.png

However, I was able to link it directly to the readme (to see whether its working)

I’ve also tried to provide relative link (my project structure is)

```
myProject
-file1
-logo.png
-docs
 - mkdocs.yml
 - docs
 - logo.png
 - logo.svg
```

and change the refernace like

```
theme:
  name: 'material'
  logo:
     icon: 'logo.png’
```

which didnt work either…

If I change it to something else from https://material.io/resources/icons/?icon=sports_cricket&style=baseline

it works

```
theme:
  name: 'material'
  logo:
     icon: ‘3d_rotation’
```

Any idea what am I missing here ? does png is not supported ?

if there is some referance how to do it with custom icon it will help me a lot as Im blocked now :(

This is the default logo that we want to change

[image]

**update**

I was able to add `favicon` which **works** with `.png` and add also `.svg` icon but and referance it to the logo entry and still doesnt work ...any idea?

```
theme:
  name: 'material'
  favicon: 'logo.png’
  logo:
     icon: 'logo.svg’
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe you must place the logo in a directory where main page can find it. Try

```
theme:
    name: 'material'
    logo: 'img/logo.png'
```

and place logo.png in an `img` directory in the `docs` directory.
The file structure should look like

```
MyProject
-mkdocs.yml
-docs
    -index.md
    -img
        -logo.png
```

Im surprised things work for you at all when your yml file is placed the docs directory and not in the root dir.

Comment: The docs don't make it clear, but when using a custom image, drop the icon: prefix, and just do logo: mylogo.png